# Error with Json value from controller to use in view, Laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel

I can't convert Json value that i got from my controller to the proper javascript readable value.

This is my controller

```
    $room = Room::
        select('id', 'name', 'capacity', 'status')
        ->get();

    $this->rooms = json_encode($room);;

    return view('admin.rooms.index', $this->data);
```

on the view, {!!$room!!} gives

[
{"id":1,"name":"room1","capacity":4,"status":"dirty"},{"id":2,"name":"room2","capacity":5,"status":"clean"},{"id":3,"name":"room3","capacity":5,"status":"clean"}
]

so i get json value i need..

when i use  {!!$room!!} in my script

```
               function loadResources() {
                    $.post( "{!!$rooms!!}",
                    { capacity: $("#filter").val() },
                    function(data) {
                        dp.resources = data;
                        dp.update();
                    });
                }
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

thats the error i get..

if i create a file and put json value in a file

```
               function loadResources() {
                    $.post( "room.json" ,
                    { capacity: $("#filter").val() },
                    function(data) {
                        dp.resources = data;
                        dp.update();
                    });
                }
```

Everythins works fine..

i tried JSON.parse(), to make the value javascript readable but failed.

How can i use that json value in my javascript code

Comment: try $.post( json_decode({!!$rooms!!}) in the loadresources function

Comment: Error.. Uncaught ReferenceError: json_decode is not defined.. When i looked that up, i found that " you cannot use json_decode in JS json_decode is PHP function "

Comment: @stoneshak, are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: Not really.. i decided to use something else..

Comment: If you found a solution or workaround, you too can post an answer and accept that. :) So if some other person is looking for answer can have one.

Answer (score 0):

Do not json_encode the result set.

Pass the entire object to the view like this:

```
$room = Room::
        select('id', 'name', 'capacity', 'status')
        ->get();

return view('admin.rooms.index', $room);
```

Then in the view what you can do to retrieve the value from the above passed data is:

```
{{$room->id}}
```

Comment: İ know how to get the value from that data.. did you actually read the question?

Answer (score 0):

try encoding the rooms array in the view i.e in javascript section. Then pass it to loadResources function.